# Reduce 12V to 5V on switch power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I have a switch power supply which has a TL431 as reference for regulation.
It outputs 12V DC, but I would like to change this to 5V in a efficient way.

I know I can use a 7805 or some linear regulator or a buck down converter, but I want to change the output directly into the PS circuits.

Can I change the output from 12V to 5V?
[image]

Edit 1:
I changed R1 for a 6.8K, R3 for 10K, R4 for a 10k pot (which varies from 0 to 5K in this configuration)

Changed R8 for a 47 Ohms and added a load resistor in parallel of R2 with 150 Ohms

Now Without load the Output voltage is 5.64V, but with a 4 Ohms Load the Voltage Drops to 3.4V

Comment: Why not just buy a 5VDC power adapter and run your connecting circuit off that?

Comment: i have many power adapters like this and want to use then, and there is allways the academic side of view

Comment: Keep in mind that by altering the output voltage, you may compromise the stability and response of the power supply.

Comment: @Stonie: There is always that chance, but from the nature of the feedback, it looks like the input pulses are simply shut down when the output regulation threshold is reached.  That kind of control scheme may have more ripple than something fancier, but it is highly robust and stable.

Comment: I Agree with @OlinLathrop this is why i am making this project, i know that i can't reach very low voltages with this configuration, but i believe 5V can be reached with such stability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed the R1 to 6,8K, R4 to a 10K pot and R3 to 10K. 
Just changed the R8 resistor by a 47 ohms and the ouput is much stable
Added a 150 ohm in parallel of R2 220 ohm to reach 90 ohms in parallel with the ouput 
I put the voltmeter right on the supply bornes and everything worked fine, without load, 5,64V and with Load 4,8V.

Answer (score 2):

Recalculate your output voltage resistor divider to give 2.5 V to the TL431 at 5 V output. Say 10k and 10k.

Not beautiful in any way and highly simplified schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpBq8J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: so, i changed the voltage divisor into one resistor and one 10 k trimpot but when i archieve the 5v with an open output and put a load, the voltage decreases

Comment: @Luizhenriquedinizferreira Adjust to 5 V under load. Unloaded voltage will always be higher. If this is a problem over a large rage, you may need to one or more bias resistors too.

Comment: sure, the range is very high, so in the diagram i drawed, what is the bias resistor?

Comment: my diagram shows a 250 ohms resistor which serves as load when the supply is open

Comment: R3 in the diagram, it may need a lower value when your output voltage is lower. What voltage do you measure at no load and full load?

Comment: Updated schematic! Neat! Calculate what current flows though R7 and R8 at 12 V and recalculate both to give the same current or slightly less at 5 V.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56378/discussion-between-luiz-henrique-diniz-ferreira-and-winny).

Answer (score 1):

First start by understanding how the existing circuit works.  The relevant part of your schematic is:

[image]

I don't know what a TIL431 is, so I'll answer as if it were a TL431.

The TL431 turns on when it's gate input goes above 2.5 V.  When that happens, current flows thru U1, turning on its output transistor.  Presumably, that is used on the hot side of the isolation to turn off the switching pulses, thereby not causing the overall output voltage to rise further.

The resistor divider chain of R3, R1, and R4 feed the 2.5 V threshold voltage into D1 when the supply output is the desired 12 V.  However, working thru this divider shows that it would take at least 64 V on the output to trigger D1.  At 12 V output the divider would only produce at most 470 mV.  Perhaps that's the difference between a TIL431 and a TL431, but without a datasheet we don't know.

In any case, to get a particular output voltage, you change the R3,R1,R4 divider to produce the threshold voltage that triggers D1 when the top of the divider is at the voltage you want.

With a real TL431 that has a 2.5 V threshold, two equal resistors is all you need since the divider needs to make half the output voltage.  In that case, replace R3 and R1 with 10 kΩ, and R4 with another 10 kΩ, for example.

### Added

You now say D1 is really a TL431.  That makes sense by itself, but now the R3,R1,R4 voltage divider makes no sense for 12 V out.  There is clearly something you're not telling us, so going into this further is pointless since there is a good chance it won't actually apply to your circuit, whatever your circuit really is.

You should understand what R8 and R7 do before modifying this supply for 5 V out, but again, without the real circuit there is too much chance getting into details will just be a waste of time.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, me schematic was wrong, I just edited the post with the true revised schematic

Comment: I edited tehe schematic, before the ref was between r1 and r4 but the correct is between r1 and r3, now it makes sense for 12V